# Doing event.preventDefault() on $stateChangeStart creates a duplicate state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

`one` and `two` are states created with the *ui-router* with urls `/one` and `/two`. Suppose that I navigate the following states:

`two` -> `one`

(in the browser bar I see `/two` -> `/one`)

Then I click the *back* button but instead of transitioning back to `two` I purposely prevent the change of state like so:

```
   $scope.firstTime = true;

   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
          if ($scope.firstTime) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $scope.firstTime = false;
          }
        });
```

Now I click *back* again, this time the change of state is not prevented but instead of going back to `two`, the *ui-router* remains on state `one` (`/one`).... now if I click back again I can go back to state `two` (`/two`).

How do I prevent ui-router from duplicating state `one` the first time I click *back*?

Comment: Nope, never found a solution...